# Coding Meetup #9 - Higher-Order Functions Series - Is the meetup age-diverse?

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to complete Coding Meetup #9 on CodeWars.

How can I complete this only using for loops and if/else statements?

Here is the CodeWars Kata question:

> You will be given an array of objects (associative arrays in PHP)
> representing data about developers who have signed up to attend the
> next coding meetup that you are organising.
>
> Your task is to return: true if developers from all of the following
> age groups have signed up: teens, twenties, thirties, forties,
> fifties, sixties, seventies, eighties, nineties, centenarian (at least
> 100 years young). false otherwise.
>
> For example, given the following input array:
>
> ```
> var list = [
>     { firstName: 'Harry', lastName: 'K.', country: 'Brazil', continent: 'Americas', age: 19, language: 'Python' },
>     { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 29, language: 'JavaScript' },
>     { firstName: 'Jing', lastName: 'X.', country: 'China', continent: 'Asia', age: 39, language: 'Ruby' },
>     { firstName: 'Noa', lastName: 'A.', country: 'Israel', continent: 'Asia', age: 40, language: 'Ruby' },
>     { firstName: 'Andrei', lastName: 'E.', country: 'Romania', continent: 'Europe', age: 59, language: 'C' },
>     { firstName: 'Maria', lastName: 'S.', country: 'Peru', continent: 'Americas', age: 60, language: 'C' },
>     { firstName: 'Lukas', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Croatia', continent: 'Europe', age: 75, language: 'Python' },
>     { firstName: 'Chloe', lastName: 'K.', country: 'Guernsey', continent: 'Europe', age: 88, language: 'Ruby' },
>     { firstName: 'Viktoria', lastName: 'W.', country: 'Bulgaria', continent: 'Europe', age: 98, language: 'PHP' },
>     { firstName: 'Piotr', lastName: 'B.', country: 'Poland', continent: 'Europe', age: 128, language: 'JavaScript' }
>   ];
> ```
>
> Your function should return true as there is at least one developer
> from each age group

Here is my code:

```
function isAgeDiverse(list) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].age >= 18) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive but working approach:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }

function isAgeDiverse(list) {
    requiredAgeGroups = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    availableAgeGroups = [];

    list.forEach(el => {
        availableAgeGroups.push(Math.floor(el.age / 10));
    });

    availableAgeGroups = availableAgeGroups.filter(onlyUnique);

    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++ ){
       if (availableAgeGroups.indexOf(i) == -1){
           return false;
       }
    }

    availableAgeGroups = availableAgeGroups.filter((i) => i > 9);

    return availableAgeGroups.length > 0;

}
```